# If Value is present in two consecutive months , display only one month in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would want to check ID in consecutive months, IF Same ID is present in two consecutive months then consider  that ID only for 1st month.
If ID's are not in consecutive month then show the distinct ID's grouped by start date month.(We consider only start date)
For example, ID 1 is present in start date months january and Feb , then Distinct count of this ID will be 1 in Jan, how ever ID 2 and 3 are
present in Jan and March and Feb and May Resp, now I would like to see this distinct count of ID in Jan and March.
Current Data

Table1:

```
ID    StartDate      EndDate
1     2017-01-12     2017-01-28
1     2017-01-19     2017-01-28
1     2017-01-29     2017-02-11
1     2017-02-01     2017-02-11
1     2017-02-19     2017-02-24
2     2017-01-12     2017-01-28
2     2017-01-19     2017-01-28
2     2017-03-09     2017-03-20
3     2017-02-12     2017-02-28
3     2017-02-19     2017-02-28
3     2017-05-05     2017-05-29
3     2017-05-09     2017-05-29
```

I tried with below logic bt I know I am missing on something here.

```
select t.* from Table1 t
join Table1 t t1
on t1.ID=t.ID 
and datepart(mm,t.StartDate)<> datepart(mm,t1.StartDate)+1
```

Expected Result:

```
DistinctCount     StartDateMonth(In Numbers)
   1                 1(Jan)
   2                 1(Jan)
   2                 3(March)
   3                 2(Feb)
   3                 5(May)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution. The thinking for this is:

1) Round all the dates to the first of the month, then work with the distinct dataset of (ID, StartDateRounded). From your dataset, the result should look like this:

```
ID     StartDateRounded

1      2017-01-01
1      2017-02-01
2      2017-01-01
2      2017-03-01
3      2017-02-01
3      2017-05-01
```

2) From this consolidated dataset, find all records by ID that do not have a record for the previous month (which means it's not a consecutive month and thus is a beginning of a new data point). This is your final dataset

```
with DatesTable AS 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ID
    ,DATEADD(month,DateDiff(month,0,StartDate),0) StartDateRounded
    ,DATEADD(month,DateDiff(month,0,StartDate)+1,0) StartDateRoundedPlusOne
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT t1.ID, DatePart(month,t1.StartDateRounded) AS StartDateMonth
  FROM DatesTable t1
    LEFT JOIN DatesTable t2
      ON t1.ID = t2.ID
        AND t1.StartDateRounded = t2.StartDateRoundedPlusOne
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL; --Verify no record exists for prior month
```

[sqlfiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76c57/15) for reference. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Just need to take advantage of the [`lag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) on the inner query to compare values between rows, and apply the logic in question on the middle query, and then do a final select.

```
/*SAMPLE DATA*/
create table #table1
    (
        ID int not null
        , StartDate date not null
        , EndDate date null
    )

insert into #table1
values (1, '2017-01-12', '2017-01-28')
    , (1, '2017-01-19', '2017-01-28')
    , (1, '2017-01-29', '2017-02-11')
    , (1, '2017-02-01', '2017-02-11')
    , (1, '2017-02-19', '2017-02-24')
    , (2, '2017-01-12', '2017-01-28')
    , (2, '2017-01-19', '2017-01-28')
    , (2, '2017-03-09', '2017-03-20')
    , (3, '2017-02-12', '2017-02-28')
    , (3, '2017-02-19', '2017-02-28')
    , (3, '2017-05-05', '2017-05-29')
    , (3, '2017-05-09', '2017-05-29')

/*ANSWER*/

--Final Select
select c.ID
, c.StartDateMonth
from (
    --Compare record values to rule a record in/out based on OP's logic
    select b.ID
    , b.StartDateMonth
    , case when b.StartDateMonth = b.StartDateMonthPrev then 0 --still the same month?
           when b.StartDateMonth = b.StartDateMonthPrev + 1 then 0 --immediately prior month?
           when b.StartDateMonth = 1 and b.StartDateMonthPrev = 12 then 0 --Dec/Jan combo
           else 1
      end as IncludeFlag
    from (
        --pull StartDateMonth of previous record into current record
        select a.ID
        , datepart(mm, a.StartDate) as StartDateMonth
        , lag(datepart(mm, a.StartDate), 1, NULL) over (partition by a.ID order by a.StartDate asc) as StartDateMonthPrev
        from #table1 as a
        ) as b
    ) as c
where 1=1
and c.IncludeFlag = 1
```

**Output:**

```
+----+----------------+
| ID | StartDateMonth |
+----+----------------+
|  1 |              1 |
|  2 |              1 |
|  2 |              3 |
|  3 |              2 |
|  3 |              5 |
+----+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query,

```
SELECT  ID,MIN(YEARMONTH) AS  YEARMONTH
FROM    (
        SELECT  ID
                ,YEAR([StartDate])*100+MONTH([StartDate])       AS YEARMONTH
                ,LAG(YEAR([StartDate])*100+MONTH([StartDate])) 
                                            OVER(ORDER BY ID)   AS PREVYEARMONTH
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)                 AS ROW_NO
        FROM    @Table1
        GROUP BY ID,((YEAR([StartDate])*100)+MONTH([StartDate]))
)   AS T
GROUP BY ID
    ,(CASE WHEN YEARMONTH - PREVYEARMONTH > 1 THEN ROW_NO ELSE 0 END)
ORDER BY ID
```

Output:

```
ID  YEARMONTH
1   201701
2   201701
2   201703
3   201702
3   201705
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys. most of the logic seemed to work..but I tried just with below one and I Was good with thiis.

```
SELECT t1.ID, DatePart(month,t1.Startdate) AS StartDateMonth
  FROM DatesTable t1
    LEFT JOIN DatesTable t2
      ON t1.ID = t2.ID
        AND DatePart(month,t1.Startdate)  = DatePart(month,t2.Startdate)+1
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL;
```

Thanks again

Comment: Not exactly 100% sure what your ultimate goal is but I have a feeling this query will cause you problems once you get towards the end of the year (specifically using DatePart(month,date)). Include the following records in your input table and see if this query returns the results you expect for ID 4:

(4, '2018-12-12', '2018-12-28'),
(4, '2019-01-19', '2019-01-28')

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I wrote my first query without checking, believed that will work correctly. This is my updated version, should be faster than other solutions

```
select
    id
    , min(st)%12 --this will return start month
    , min(st)/12 + 1 --this will return year, just in case if you need it
from (
    select
        id, st, gr = st - row_number() over (partition by ID order by st)
    from (
        select
            distinct ID, st = (year(StartDate) - 1) * 12 + month(StartDate)
        from
            #table2
    ) t
) t
group by id, gr
```